# Java Melody Integration with NON WEB APPLICATION

Tags: java

Is it true that java melody can only be integrated with Java EE web applications?

I would like it to monitor my application which is built using the jpos framework i.e. jpos given mbeans are there.
Can I integrate it with a jpos (mBeans) based application?

Answer (score 2):

In the Java Melody Advanced User's guide, there is a section explaining how to monitor a non-webapp/no-server standalone application:

[Embedding JavaMelody in a standalone app](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#embedding-javamelody-in-a-standalone-app)

In order to display JavaMelody analysis within a browser, the advice is to include a Jetty server. For this, you will need to make an "EmbeddedServer" class, and run it from the app: `EmbeddedServer.start(8080, parameters);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EJB, all you have to do is add the melody jar files, and then on eja-jar.xml file you use:

```
...
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <interceptor-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringInterceptor</interceptor-class>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
<assembly-descriptor>
    <interceptor-binding>
        <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
        <interceptor-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringInterceptor</interceptor-class>
    </interceptor-binding>
</assembly-descriptor>
....
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use javamelody to monitor pretty much anything, it just might be a little more difficult to integrate it.

Comment: Can you please explain more about how this can be done?